# Does Logstash support BCFIPS ? if so How to make Log Stash plugin to BFIPS compliant?

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to make my logstash input plugin BCFIPS compliant. I have added Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider()); to register fips provider in my plugin class. Then I copied my plugin to logstash and when try to run it... I am getting `"not able to configure plugins: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/BouncyCastleFipsProvider..."` 
Please help me setting up BCFIPS in logstash plugin ?